# Why does this site have comparatively lots of posts for me to review?

Tags: discussion, review, stackexchange, stackoverflow

Why do I find my *review section* to have comparatively lots of "Late review" and "First Answers" posts? On [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) (which I believe is much popular than superuser) and [android.stackexchange](http://android.stackexchange.com), I often get 0 posts to review. The frequency of new posts that turns up to review in superuser is also much higher than these two sites.

My question is, Does it have to do with my reputation points or something?

But then that wouldn't make sense I guess.. I don't have much rep in superuser.. 

[image: profile for Power-Inside at Super User, Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users]

[image: profile for Power-Inside at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

( just around 130, similar to my points at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)) and I have above 1k on [android.stackexchange.com](http://android.stackexchange.com)

[image: profile for Power-Inside at Android Enthusiasts, Q&A for enthusiasts and power users of the Android operating system]

Or is this just some glitchy internal algorithm or the fact that superuser has less number of reviewers than SO and A.SE?

Comment: How many are "lots"? Maybe a dozen? Significantly more?

Comment: @DanielBeck A double digit number.. on average, above 15.. while on others, its usually 3, 5 or 0 most of the time.

Comment: Lot more people visit & act on the review queue on [so]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now that you mention it, I was somewhat curious.  I ran the following simple query on both Super User and Stack Overflow to see how many users had edit permission (>= 2000 reputation):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    Users
WHERE 
    Users.Reputation >= 2000
```

Which returns 488 for Super User, and 18890 for Stack Overflow.  As a percentage of total users (i.e. commenting out the `WHERE` clause in the above query), and repeating the query for Android SE while we're at it, we get:

```
Super User:     (  488 /  136571) x 100% = 0.357%
Stack Overflow: (18890 / 1582958) x 100% = 1.193%
Android SE:     (   32 /   19260) x 100% = 0.166%
```

Given these numbers, it appears as though Super User has roughly 3.3 times *less* editors as a percentage of all users on the site as compared to Stack Overflow.

---

I also thought it would be cool to evaluate the above based on number of questions; so below are two values, the first is total questions + answers divided by users, the second is questions + answers divided by number of users w/ edit permissions:

```
Super User:     (151k + 265k) / 136571 ~= 3.1 Posts/User
                (151k + 265k) /    488 ~= 852 Posts/User w/ Edit Perms

Stack Overflow: (4.2m + 8m) / 1582958  ~= 7.7 Posts/User
                (4.2m + 8m) /   18890  ~= 646 Posts/User w/ Edit Perms

Android SE:     (11k + 16k) / 19260    ~= 1.4 Posts/User 
                (11k + 16k) /    32    ~= 844 Posts/User w/ Edit Perms
```

Thus, it looks as though Super User has more posts per user than Android.SE, with a similar number of posts per editors.  However, Super User also has seven times the volume of posts, which is likely a big factor.  Stack Overflow has a significantly higher number of posts per user, but also has a proportionally higher number of editors, obtaining the lowest number of posts per editors.

Comment: Nice! That makes sense on SO's behalf. (more editors, less posts to review) But I get low number of review posts on A.SE compared to SU. (I guess maybe it has to do with editors being less active on SU.)

Comment: I know that the handful of folks with privs to the Review queues on Android are _very_ active there.